# Condition In Array PHP

Tags: php, arrays, conditional-statements

I am confused what to write titles that fit with my problem. Well, I have two arrays like the following :

the first array is called "mahasiswa"

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [npm] => 1123123123
            [nama] => LINDA 
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [npm] => 121323131
            [nama] => SETIADI
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [npm] => 12312312
            [nama] => WIWIN
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [npm] => 12345678910
            [nama] => ABDUL IMAN
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [npm] => 12355141
            [nama] => KOKOM
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [npm] => 123U4148U90
            [nama] => JIHAN 
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [npm] => 978687999
            [nama] => KURNIA 
        )
)
```

and this is called "piutang"

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [total] => 14600000
            [nama] => KOKOM
            [npm] => 12355141
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [total] => 8000000
            [nama] => KURNIA
            [npm] => 978687999
        )

)
```

Now I have to do the conditioning of the two arrays, so i can to combine them into a new array...this is an example of my code :

```
$i = 0;
$rekappiutang = array();
foreach ($mahasiswa as $row) {
   foreach ($piutang as $key=>$val) {
      if ($val['npm'] == $row['npm']) {
         $rekappiutang[$i]['npm']  = $row['npm'];
         $rekappiutang[$i]['nama'] = $row['nama'];
         $rekappiutang[$i]['totalpiutang']  = $val['total'];
       } else {
         $rekappiutang[$i]['npm']  = $row['npm'];
         $rekappiutang[$i]['nama'] = $row['nama'];
         $rekappiutang[$i]['totalpiutang'] = 0;
       }                  
   }
   $i++;
}
```

result of the code above should be like this :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [npm] => 1123123123
            [nama] => LINDA 
            [totalpiutang] => 0
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [npm] => 121323131
            [nama] => SETIADI
            [totalpiutang] => 0
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [npm] => 12312312
            [nama] => WIWIN
            [totalpiutang] => 0
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [npm] => 12345678910
            [nama] => ABDUL IMAN
            [totalpiutang] => 0
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [npm] => 12355141
            [nama] => KOKOM
            [totalpiutang] => 14600000
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [npm] => 123U4148U90
            [nama] => JIHAN 
            [totalpiutang] => 0
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [npm] => 978687999
            [nama] => KURNIA 
            [totalpiutang] => 8000000
        )
)
```

but i always got this output :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [npm] => 1123123123
            [nama] => LINDA 
            [totalpiutang] => 0
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [npm] => 121323131
            [nama] => SETIADI
            [totalpiutang] => 0
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [npm] => 12312312
            [nama] => WIWIN
            [totalpiutang] => 0
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [npm] => 12345678910
            [nama] => ABDUL IMAN
            [totalpiutang] => 0
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [npm] => 12355141
            [nama] => KOKOM
            [totalpiutang] => 0
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [npm] => 123U4148U90
            [nama] => JIHAN 
            [totalpiutang] => 0
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [npm] => 978687999
            [nama] => KURNIA 
            [totalpiutang] => 8000000
        )
)
```

data with value name "KOKOM" is always null, how i fix them? thank you

Comment: Is `$v['npm'] == $row['npm']` a typo in your question? it should be `$val['npm']`.

Comment: oh yes....it's typo in my question..not in my code...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is your index, each time you get inside the second foreach you overwrite the index position, for example if you get in the first iteration your index will be 0, in the second iteration your index will still be 0 and in this case you'll loose the information you collected in the first iteration, you can do two things depending on how you want to condition your array, you could break outside the first foreach if you find something (if that's what you want to obtain) like this:

```
if ($val['npm'] == $row['npm']) {
     $rekappiutang[$i]['npm']  = $row['npm'];
     $rekappiutang[$i]['nama'] = $row['nama'];
     $rekappiutang[$i]['totalpiutang']  = $val['total'];
    break;
}
```

Or you could increment the index at the end of the first foreach thus having all the result stored and no overwriting.

KURNIA works only because it's the last element of the array and after that the foreach breaks automatically.

Comment: hey, it's working! i thought "break" is same with "die" or "exit"...awasome....thank you so much for your help :D